# Fully disable WooCommerce Endpoints

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've searched the web a lot for this but i did not found an answer yet.
So i rely on the specialists here.

I want to disable some woocommerce endpoints. The web told me to unset the woocommerce menu items via `woocommerce_account_menu_items` hook like:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_remove_my_account_links' );
function my_remove_my_account_links( $menu_links ){
    
    /**
     * Uncomment the appropriate lines to remove specific
     * endpoints in the WooCommerce My Account screen.
     */
    
    //unset( $menu_links['dashboard'] );        // Remove Dashboard
    //unset( $menu_links['edit-address'] );     // Addresses
    //unset( $menu_links['payment-methods'] );  // Remove Payment Methods
    //unset( $menu_links['orders'] );           // Remove Orders
    //unset( $menu_links['downloads'] );        // Disable Downloads
    //unset( $menu_links['edit-account'] );     // Remove Account details tab
    //unset( $menu_links['customer-logout'] );  // Remove Logout link
    
    return $menu_links;
}
```

BUT the big problem here is that this only removes the menu links in the frontend.
I can still enter the unset endpoints via direct URL. So when i enter `https://example.de/myaccount/[unset-endpoint]` i am still abled to reach the content.

I found one way to redirect access via direct URL entry. I used the hook `woocommerce_before_account_payment_methods` which is located inside the payment methods template (/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/payment-methods.php) to redirect back to the dashboard:

```
function redirect_forbidden_access_account_endpoints(){
   wp_redirect(wc_get_account_endpoint_url('dashboard'));
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_account_payment_methods', 'redirect_forbidden_access_account_endpoints');
```

This works like a charme BUT only for the `payment-methods` endpoint. I tried this for the native `downloads` endpoint and a custom endpoint aswell without success.

So my question is: I there a solid solution to redirect URL access from specific disabled woocommerce endpoints to the dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: Yes there is! My hook was wrong. I used the wp hook now. Is that legal?

```
function redirect_forbidden_access(){
    $current_endpoint = WC()->query->get_current_endpoint();
    if($current_endpoint == "payment-methods" 
      || $current_endpoint == "add-payment-method"
      || $current_endpoint == "edit-payment-method" 
      || $current_endpoint == "[custom-endpoint]")
    {
        wp_redirect(wc_get_account_endpoint_url('dashboard'));
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'redirect_forbidden_access');
```

This does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using these 2 ways:

1. **Put the Empty value in backend settings** 
   Go to WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced then in Account endpoints
   input you can remove the values for the specific endpoints and save
   the empty values. 

   By this, you will not see the endpoint page or menu items on the account page and if you access the url, you'll see the homepage on the accessed url.
2. **Unset the query vars** 
   You can unset the query vars using the filter hook.
   https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php#L85  
   in Line `85` you can find the function that has all the query vars.  

   https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php#L232  
   And in line 232, you can find the function to get query vars, it has the filter as well. You can use the filter and unset the desired endpoint.  

   If you use this method, you'll have to unset the item from the nav menu items as well, You'll also need to save permalink settings again.  

   Then if you access the endpoint the url, you'll see the homepage on the accessed url.

In both cases, you won't see a 404 page.

Comment: I have an additional problem. I want to enable/disable some menu items programmatically based on the current logged in user. So the first way may work, but only for every user. I need to have a dynamic choice for this. Can you clarify your second way? Isnt this the already discribed way in my question?

Comment: In a 2nd way, you're removing the query variable along with menu items because as you mentioned if you just remove menu items, the page is still accessible by url, and that is because the query variable for the rewrite rule still exists. we need to remove query variables to disable rewrite rules and all the feature that is written by checking that query variable.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of redirect and removing endpoints from query vars worked for me.

Without the redirect, the endpoints would still display the content from the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/dashboard.php` welcome page.

```php
<?php
    const DISABLED_WC_ENDPOINTS = [
        'bookings',
        'edit-address',
        'downloads',
        'orders',
    ];
    
    add_action(
        'init',
        static function () {
            add_filter(
                'woocommerce_get_query_vars',
                static function(array $vars) {
                    foreach (DISABLED_WC_ENDPOINTS as $rem) {
                        unset($vars[$rem]);
                    }
                    return $vars;
                },
                0
            );
        }
    );

    add_action(
        'template_redirect',
        static function() {
            $baseEndpoint = 'my-account';
            foreach (DISABLED_WC_ENDPOINTS as $endpoint) {
                if ('/' . $baseEndpoint . '/' . $endpoint . '/' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
                    wp_redirect('/' . $baseEndpoint, 301);
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    );
```